# Error in tabular

Tags: tables, align

I want to achieve the following result.
[image: table]

I have written the following code but it is giving me error. I think the problem is in new-command. (I'm new in defining new commands, so a little bit explanation is appreciated)

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\tableequation}[1]{%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
{\begin{flalign}#1&&&\end{flalign}}%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {
@{}
>{\linespread{1.2}\selectfont}m{6cm}
@{}
m{6cm}
@{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{ |l| }{\textbf{Requirements of inner product}}\\
\midrule
\emph{Commutative:} & \tableequation{ \textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v} = \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{u}, }\\
\emph{Nonnegative:} & 
\tableequation{ 
\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{u} &> 0 && \text{for all \textbf{u} \ne 0, }\\ 
&=0 && \text{for \textbf{u} = 0,}\\ 
}\\
\emph{Linear:} & \tableequation{ (\alpha \textbf{u} + \beta \textbf{v}) \cdot \textbf{w} = \alpha(\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{w}) + \beta(\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{w}), }
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`

Comment: what is the difference between two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a `tabular` environment to obtain this result: `alignat` will do it easily. I propose a second variant, with a simpler code, which looks nicer, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} %requirement for the flalign environment
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \setlength{\aboverulesep}{1ex}
  \setlength{\belowrulesep}{1ex}
  \begin{alignat}{3}
    \toprule
    \shortintertext{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Requirements of inner product}\smallskip}
    \emph{Commutative:} & \qquad & \mathbf{u} · \mathbf{v} & {}={} & & \mathbf{v} · \mathbf{u}, \\
    \emph{Nonnegative:} & & \mathbf{u} · \mathbf{u} > 0 & & & \text{for all } \mathbf{u} \ne 0, \notag \\
                        & & = 0 & & & \text{for } \mathbf{u} = 0 \\
    \emph{Linear:} & & (α\mathbf{u} + β\mathbf{v}) · \mathbf{w} & {}={} & & α(\mathbf{u} · \mathbf{w}) + β(\mathbf{v} · \mathbf{w}), \\
    \bottomrule\notag
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
  \setlength{\aboverulesep}{1ex}
  \setlength{\belowrulesep}{1ex}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \toprule
    \shortintertext{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Requirements of inner product}\smallskip}
    \emph{Commutative:} & \qquad & \mathbf{u} · \mathbf{v} & = \mathbf{v} · \mathbf{u}, \\
    \emph{Nonnegative:} & & \mathbf{u} · \mathbf{u} & > 0 \quad\text{for all } \mathbf{u} \ne 0, \notag \\
                        & & & = 0 \quad \text{for } \mathbf{u} = 0 \\
    \emph{Linear:} & & (α\mathbf{u} + β\mathbf{v}) · \mathbf{w} & = α(\mathbf{u} · \mathbf{w}) + β(\mathbf{v} · \mathbf{w}), \\
    \bottomrule\notag
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the `amsmath` for the flalign environment. Also there was a missing `\\` before your bottomrule, see inline comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %requirement for the flalign environment
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\tableequation}[1]{%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
{\begin{flalign}#1&&&\end{flalign}}%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {
@{}
>{\linespread{1.2}\selectfont}m{6cm}
@{}
m{6cm}
@{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{ |l| }{\textbf{Requirements of inner product}}\\
\midrule
\emph{Commutative:} & \tableequation{ \textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v} = \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{u}, }\\
\emph{Nonnegative:} & 
\tableequation{ 
\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{u} &> 0 && \text{for all \textbf{u} \ne 0, }\\ 
&=0 && \text{for \textbf{u} = 0,}\\ 
}\\
\emph{Linear:} & \tableequation{ (\alpha \textbf{u} + \beta \textbf{v}) \cdot \textbf{w} = \alpha(\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{w}) + \beta(\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{w}), }\\ %missing \\ in the original code
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting errors. Also instead of equation no (2),(3) and (4) I just want a single equation number.

Comment: could you be more specific about the error you are getting? I was under the impression it was a compilation error. Are you able to compile the code?

Comment: I'm getting compilation error. 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.28 }
      \\
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\textdef@ ...th {#1}\let \f@size #2\selectfont #3}
                                                  }
l.28 }

Comment: the code posted in the body of my answer compiles fine here. Have you copy/pasted it?

Comment: yes I have copy/pasted the code.

Comment: I was missing to put `$` around \ne  in "nonnegative" row. Now it is working.

Comment: But in the second equation, I'm getting two numbering of the equation. I just want a single number.

Comment: @domenicocamasta Your code doesn't compile. I don't need to run it in order to state that. Looking at the snippet `\text{for all \textbf{u} \ne 0}` suffices.

Comment: @egreg My default compiler is set to lualatex, that's why it works here.

Comment: @domenicocamasta OK, but the result is wrong anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as you can see in the screenshot it is typeset as not equal, the only visible error is the lack of the space between not equal and the number

Comment: @egreg Yeah, I was not looking at the content at all, just checking the compilation

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment, you get a /= from \ne in text mode if you have previously used math, although that is really just by luck, most \mathchardef defined commands used in text mode give an error in classic tex but are error free but typeset as essential random nonsense in luatex if you use the classic tex math encodings

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions: the first is a bit complicated because we need to emulate `booktabs` but using `flalign`. The second one is more natural. I removed one of the conditions, as it follows from the last one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% don't break

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\newcommand{\eqsep}{\mathrel{\hphantom{=}}}

\hrule height \heavyrulewidth
\vspace{\belowrulesep}
\textbf{Requirements of inner product}

\vspace{\aboverulesep}
\hrule height \lightrulewidth
\vspace{\belowrulesep}
\begin{flalign}
&\text{\emph{Commutative}:} & 
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}     &= \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}, &\\
&\text{\emph{Nonnegative}:} & 
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} > 0 &\eqsep \text{for all $\mathbf{u} \ne 0$, } &\nonumber\\ 
&&
                           {} = 0 &\eqsep \text{for $\mathbf{u} = 0$,} &\\ 
&\text{\emph{Linear}:} &
  (\alpha \mathbf{u} + \beta \mathbf{v}) \cdot \mathbf{w} &= 
    \alpha(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{w}) + \beta(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}). &
\end{flalign}

\vspace{\aboverulesep}
\hrule height \heavyrulewidth
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]
\[
\newcommand{\eqsep}{\mathrel{\hphantom{=}}}
\newcommand{\addnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  >{$}r<{$}@{\extracolsep{0pt}}
  >{${}}c<{{}$}
  >{$}l<{$}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  r
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Requirements of inner product}\\
\midrule
\emph{Commutative} & 
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} &= &\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}, & \addnumber \\
\addlinespace
\emph{Positive}: & 
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} > 0 & &\text{for all $\mathbf{u} \ne 0$, } & \addnumber \\
\addlinespace
\emph{Linear}: &
  (\alpha \mathbf{u} + \beta \mathbf{v}) \cdot \mathbf{w} &= &
  \alpha(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{w}) + \beta(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}). & \addnumber \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

After `\addnumber` you can add `\label`, if you want.

[image]

Comment: The solution is very interesting although I'm finding it a like hard to grasp. Could you give a little bit of explanation as I'm new to Latex.

Comment: @AnshKumar You were asking for quite a difficult alignment. `;-)`